# How to stack vectors in Theano without using scan?

Tags: python, gpu, theano

I am using theano.scan for creating stacked vector of contexts like this:

```
Y_, scan_updates = theano.scan(fn=lambda *args,**kwargs: T.concatenate(args, axis=0),outputs_info=None, sequences=dict(input = Y_, taps=range(-left_ctx,right_ctx+1)))
```

It seems that scan is so slow, that this slows down whole processing. 
In signal processing this is fairly standard operation, so I was thinking about creating a special op, just for this. 
Unfortunately, I would need also GPU implementation and grad for this op and it looks like a long shot for me. 
Can you kick me in the right direction? I have already read Extending theano documentation, but still doesn't help a lot.

Example:

in case of

```
left_ctx=right_ctx=1
```

matrix:

```
[[0.0, 0.1],
 [1.0, 1.1],
 [2.0, 2.1],
 [3.0, 3.1]]
```

would be converted to

```
[[0.0, 0.1, 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.1],
 [1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.1, 3.0, 3.1]]
```

Thank you
J

Comment: What are "stacked vector contexts" exactly? Any reference or alternate description? I have not heard of this name in signal processing.

Comment: you have a matrix of feature vectors (e.g. 100x15). lets say you want to take 5 frames at a time and stack them to one big vector so for every frame you will get vector of size (1x75). in the end you will end up with matrix 96x75 (96 because you don't have enough data on the beginning and the end of original matrix). is it better now?

Comment: I've added example to the original question.

Comment: Ah ok - basically just a sliding window.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is solvable in this way. Works now.

```
Y_= T.concatenate([Y_[c:Y_.shape[0]+c-left_ctx-right_ctx] for c in range(left_ctx+right_ctx+1)], axis=1)
```

Comment: Glad to see you found an answer - is this noticeably faster than scan?

Comment: in the above answer, must Y_ have a shape value specified?